# /v:diag stops powershell command working from MSBuild

Tags: powershell, msbuild, azure-devops

When I enable diagnostic logging the following command incorrectly includes the MSBuild TaskId in the Environment variable being set, what do I need to change to stop this happening?

```
<Exec Command="powershell -Command Write-Host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=AutoBuildNumber;]$(BuildNumber)" />
```

If my build number is 999 the 'AutoBuildNumber' should be set to `999` if `/v:diag` is set the environment variable will be, `999 (TaskId:6)`

Comment: I'd argue vso is incorrect here (or rather lacks proper parsing functionality), after all you're asking msbuild for diagnostic output. Does the output has to be via Powershell? With the Message task you can just output a nweline after BuildNumber and you're set.

Comment: @stijn I couldn't get that to work - could you provide a more complete answer with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output log text using the MsBuild message task and ad a newline after it. This gives output without the TaskId after it, though it does occur twice with diagnostic logging but I assume that is no problem. Example:

```
<Target Name="ShowBuildNumber">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildNumber>12</BuildNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="##vso[task.setvariable variable=AutoBuildNumber;]$(BuildNumber)%0a" />
</Target>
```

Output of `msbuild <projectfile> /t:ShowBuildNumber /v:diag`:

```
Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Message" (TaskId:2)
  Task Parameter:Text=##vso[task.setvariable variable=AutoBuildNumber;]12
   (TaskId:2)
  ##vso[task.setvariable variable=AutoBuildNumber;]12
   (TaskId:2)
Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the value be changed when set environment variable (##vso[task.setvariable variable=AutoBuildNumber;]$(BuildNumber)), the BuildNumber value is correct.

So, you could remove extra string through PowerShell script. For example(add {} to if block):

```
$MyBuildNum=$env:AutoBuildNumber
```

if ($MyBuildNum)

```
if($MyBuildNum.Contains("TaskId"))
{
    $MyBuildNum=$MyBuildNum.Substring(0,$MyBuildNum.IndexOf(" "));
}
```